# how to remove space between paragraph and table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm dynamically displaying a table and paragraph but how can we remove space between a paragraph and table? I tried it by doing margin and padding 0 but still space is there,

below is my code:

```js
var out = "<br/><p>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspConfirmed Batches</p>";
//var out="";
//out+="<center><table><tr><td>Confirmed Batches</td></tr></table>;
out += "<table  border='2' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0' rules=none >";
//out+="<tr><td>Confirmed Batches</td></tr>";
out += "<tr><th width='100' height='40' >&nbsp&nbspBatch Code</th><th width='100' height='45'><center>Start Date</center></th><th width='50' align='center' height='45'><center>Day</center></th><th width='120' align='center' height='45'><center>Batch time</center></th><th width='150' align='center' height='45'><center>Trainer</center></th><th width='100' align='center' height='45'><center>Frequency</center></th><th width='50' align='center' height='45' ><center>Fees</center></th><th width='110' align='center' height='45'><center>Duration</center></th></th></tr>";
$("body").append(out);
```

```css
table {
  //border:5;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 800px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  //border-color:green;
  //background-color:#EBF5FB;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #C8E786;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) *showing* us the problem.

Comment: Provide the code in such a way that some will reproduce the issue

Comment: I created a snippet for you. It does not show any issue

Comment: do you want side-by-side (paragraph and table>)

Comment: @ArchanaGupta A side note: For disabling a css definition: put it into /* */

Comment: no table should be below paragraph

Comment: then there is no issue at all. code work fine

Comment: there are some issues.. `</th></th>` at the end, `&nbsp` should be `&nbsp;` and there's no `</table>` at the end

Comment: @AlivetoDie actually still there is a space between paragraph and table but i want to make it less.

Comment: I'm not certain what space you're referring to, but if it's the left side, remove the `&nbsp;` from the `p` and `margin-left` from the `table`.

Comment: now it's starting to sound like a simple case of `line-height`

Comment: @ArchanaGupta  we arn't able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @vi5ion code is working fine i close the table and header but there is a space between paragraph and table which i want to reduce it .

Comment: @ArchanaGupta I'm sure it's fine somewhere, but I can only validate the code that you provided us and that has those errors ;) If those are fixed on your end then there's nothing actually wrong with the code. It sounds like you simply want less `line-height` in your `p`.

Comment: yeah when i wrote line-height:0px and it reduces the space. thank you @vi5ion

Comment: @ArchanaGupta Might be you want para text to touch the table border-top if so that could be reduced using line-height:15px or table margin-top:-10px or something.

Comment: okay thanx @frnt

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean

```css
th {
  height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Confirmed Batches</legend>
  <table cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0' rules=none>

    <tr>
      <th width='100'>Batch Code</th>
      <th width='100'>Start Date</th>
      <th width='50'>Day</th>
      <th width='120'>Batch time</th>
      <th width='150'>Trainer</th>
      <th width='100'>Frequency</th>
      <th width='50'>Fees</th>
      <th width='110'>Duration</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```